# Emberfire set priority of record

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

Is there a way of setting the priority of a Firebase record in emberfire / EmberJS? So far googling around has only returned me answers as to how to query for prioritised records.

Comment: `model.set('priority', desiredValue); model.save()`?

Comment: That will just set a key 'priority' to 'desiredValue'? Not what I'm after